# unable to hotswap html file in Intellij with tomcat 9

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I am new to IntelliJ, and I created a run configuration to debug my 
web application using intellij.

What I did are:

1. ran my application on intellij debug mode, and saw server start up successfully, html file got rendered correctly.

   2. modified a java file.
   3. modified a html file.
   4. saved them.
   5. clicked somewhere outside the intellij window to trigger hotswap.
   6. I saw message pop up saying only 1 file updated (It was the java file).

The issue I found is:

1. The html never got updated.

What I noticed are:

1. the java file was recompiled and "hotswapped" successfully.

   2. the html file was not "hotswapped":

      - The page in browser did not reflect the change I made.
      - html did not update even I manually refresh the web page in browser.
      - if i modify only the html file in IntelliJ, pop up alwasy would always say "loaded classes are up to date. Nothing to upload".
   3. but I verified html source is successfully changed, and the html file being deployed to the exploded war directory was also successfully changed.
   4. when I clicked the "redeploy" button, then I could see the html get updated.
   5. I have also tried adding cachingAllowed="false" to tomcat context.xml file, but no luck.

My questions are:

1. How to enable hotswap in IntelliJ with tomcat9?
   (Did I miss anything?)

   2. What is the difference between "hotswap" and "redeploy"?

Thanks.

IntelliJ version:
Ultimate 2018.1

Tomcat version:
apache-tomcat-9.0.7

[image: no update]

[image: run config]

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html. If the issue persists, please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the sample project and the steps to reproduce.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, thank you. i will read the document first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- answer

I found the answer over here:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000004090-Updating-HTML-and-Resources-without-restarting-application-server-Tomcat-8-Thymeleaf-3-Sparkjava-?page=1#community_comment_360000203964

- Reason
  as Ulisses Silva pointed out: the Thymeleaf's implementation of the TemplateResolver has a "cacheable" attribute with "true" as default attribute.
- Solution

set the "cacheable" attribute to false as follows to your TemplateResolver definition:

```
<property name="cacheable" value="false" />
```